# JQ query: Unexpected $end, expecting '}'

Tags: jq

I'm constructing a JQ query to parse below JSON object:

```
{
    "Summary": [
    {
        "FilePath": "src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java",
        "summaryId": "prod-123",
        "StartLine": 26,
        "EndLine": 26,
        "Description": "Okay"
    },
    {
        "FilePath": "src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java",
        "RecommendationId": "test-321",
        "StartLine": 26,
        "EndLine": 26,
        "Description": "Bad"
    }]
}
```

I'm expecting the output of the JQ query to be in a [SARIF](https://docs.oasis-open.org/sarif/sarif/v2.1.0/sarif-v2.1.0.html) format as below:

```
{
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-2.1.0-rtm.4",
    "runs": [
        {
            "tool":
            {
                "driver":
                {
                    "name": "Tool Name",
                    "informationUri": "google.com",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "id": "prod-123",
                            "help":
                            {
                                "text": "Okay",
                                "markdown": "Okay"
                            },
                            "properties": {
                              "tags": [ "prod"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "test-321",
                            "help":
                            {
                                "text": "Bad",
                                "markdown": "Bad"
                            },
                            "properties": {
                              "tags": [ "test"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "results": [
        {
            "ruleId": "prod-123",
            "level": "warning",
            "locations": [
            {
                "physicalLocation":
                {
                    "artifactLocation":
                    {
                        "uri": "src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java
                    },
                    "region":
                    {
                        "startLine": 25,
                        "endLine": 25
                    }
                }
            }],
            "message":
            {
                "text": "Okay"
            }
        },
        {
            "ruleId": "test-321",
            "level": "warning",
            "locations": [
            {
                "physicalLocation":
                {
                    "artifactLocation":
                    {
                        "uri": "src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java"
                    },
                    "region":
                    {
                        "startLine": 19,
                        "endLine": 19
                    }
                }
            }],
            "message":
            {
                "text": "Bad"
            }
        }]
    }
]
}
```

I've so far tried to built below JQ query, however I'm stuck with the error (see at the bottom):

```
{
        version: "2.1.0",
        "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-2.1.0-rtm.4",
        runs: [
                {
                    tool:
                    {
                        driver:
                        {
                            name: "Tool Name",
                            informationUri: "google.com",
                            rules: [ .Summary[] | select(.FilePath != ".") |
                            {
                                id: .SummaryId,
                                help:
                                {
                                    text: .Description,
                                    markdown: .Description
                                },
                                properties:
                                {
                                    tags: [.Summary[] | (
                                        if.SummaryId | contains("prod") then "prod"
                                        else "test"
                                        end)]
                                },
                                results: [.Summary[] | select(.FilePath != ".") |
                                {
                                    ruleId: .SummaryId,
                                    level: "warning",
                                    locations: [
                                    {
                                        physicalLocation:
                                        {
                                            artifactLocation:
                                            {
                                                uri: .FilePath
                                            },
                                            region:
                                            {
                                                startLine: .StartLine,
                                                endLine: .EndLine
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }],
                                    message:
                                    {
                                        text: .Description | split(".")[0]
                                    }
                                }]
                            }]
                        }
```

**jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3**

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One obvious problem is that you have nested occurrences of `.Summary[]`.  I would suggest you either try a different approach that does not involve a gigantic "query", or build up the query incrementally so that as it grows, you can more easily pinpoint any problems.

Comment: Are you invoking jq correctly? The form should be like: `jq -f program.jq input.json`

Comment: Voting to close as "typo", because the programming is obviously incomplete and jq is already telling you what it's missing – simply count the opening and closing braces and brackets: you are missing `}}]}` at the end. The program now has a different problem »Cannot index string with string "Summary"« (which would be a different question). Also note that `[ .something[] | … ]` is a complicated way to write `.something | map(…)`.

Comment: Also note `summaryId` vs `.SummaryId`. Please provide mWe. Also note that you are iterating over `.Summary[]` and then in the inner filter try to iterate over `.Summary[]` again, even though there is no such property as `Summary.Summary`

Answer (score 0):

Once the missing closing braces and brackets (`}}]}`) are added to your script, it is possible to start fixing it. You are trying to iterate over a nested `.Summary[]` array, even though you are already iterating over the top level one. Comparing this to a common programming language, this would be similar to using the same loop inside of itself. Since there is no `.Summary[].Summary` property, this will fail.

So instead of doing `.Summary[] | .SummaryId` in the inner levels, access `.SummaryId` directly, because you are already in the context of a single list item. (or `.summaryId`? unclear from your example, you mix both cases. Might even be called `RecommendationId` from the second element in the input. [Please provide proper MWE. minimal. workable.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

```json
{
    version: "2.1.0",
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-2.1.0-rtm.4",
    runs: [
        {
            tool: {
                driver: {
                    name: "Tool Name",
                    informationUri: "google.com",
                    rules: .Summary
                        | map(select(.FilePath != "."))
                        | map({
                            id: .SummaryId,
                            help: {
                                text: .Description,
                                markdown: .Description
                            },
                            properties: {
                                tags: [
                                    if (.SummaryId//.summaryId) | contains("prod")? then "prod"
                                    else "test" end
                                ]
                            },
                            results: [
                                {
                                    ruleId: (.SummaryId//.summaryId),
                                    level: "warning",
                                    locations: [
                                        {
                                            physicalLocation: {
                                                artifactLocation: {
                                                    uri: .FilePath
                                                },
                                                region: {
                                                    startLine: .StartLine,
                                                    endLine: .EndLine
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    message: {
                                        text: .Description | split(".") | first
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```